# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I was using react context api but when I added this code
`const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();`
there was the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))". My app.js is

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMqAc.png)

and My state provider is

[StateProvider.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joyDZ.png)

reducer is

[Reducer.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3jRl.png)

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on with any of your code, but `{}` isn't a valid Javascript identifier. Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of images of code. Images are not searchable, copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult to read.